nlstools error when running "overview" function: 'size' cannot exceed nrow(x) = 1
I am trying to use the overview function in nlstools to find the multiple R2 for some kinetics data. What I've done so far is below:
library(proto)
library(nls2)
library(nlstools)
#> 
#> 'nlstools' has been loaded.
#> IMPORTANT NOTICE: Most nonlinear regression models and data set examples
#> related to predictive microbiolgy have been moved to the package 'nlsMicrobio'

#Data
t=c(1,4,8,16,24,32,40,48)
K.NP=c(0.00758607,0.02106790,0.02852054,0.03280153,0.03521370,0.03683959,0.03751268,0.03760837)
NP.Data=data.frame(t,K.NP)

#The nonlinear equation (pseudo-first order)
PFO = K.NP ~ (qe * (1 - ((exp(-k1 * (x))))))

#Checking the fit
preview(PFO,NP.Data,list(qe=0.0364235,k1=0.2008984,x=t),variable=1)
#> 
#> RSS:  1.05e-05

#Creating an object of class 'nls'
nls2(formula=PFO,data=NP.Data,start=list(qe=0.0364235,k1=0.2008984,x=t),algorithm = "brute-force",control = list(maxiter = 1000))
#> Nonlinear regression model
#>   model: K.NP ~ (qe * (1 - ((exp(-k1 * (x))))))
#>    data: NP.Data
#>      qe      k1       x 
#> 0.03642 0.20090 8.00000 
#>  residual sum-of-squares: 0.0007817
#> 
#> Number of iterations to convergence: 1 
#> Achieved convergence tolerance: NA
NP.PFO<-nls2(PFO,NP.Data,list(qe=0.0364235,k1=0.2008984,x=t),algorithm = "brute-force",control = list(maxiter = 1000))

overview(NP.PFO)
#> 
#> ------
#> Error in chol2inv(object$m$Rmat()): 'size' cannot exceed nrow(x) = 1

Everything runs fine until I try running overview, and then I get the error: 'size' cannot exceed nrow(x) = 1.
I've read the documentation for the packages and looked around online. I haven't been able find anything that helps.
